# jhipster registerModule gets error "Could not add jhipster module configuration"

Tags: jhipster, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm new to jhipster/yeoman, I have generated my jhipster-module taking advantage of *generator-jhipster-module*. I followed all the steps as documented (https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-module/) in order to create the *post entity creation hook*. 
After some configuration I need to execute:

```
yo jhipster-my-module
```

the result is the module installed but with this error:

```
Could not add jhipster module configuration
```

After running, into the generated application by jhipster, the entity sub-generator

```
jhipster entity EntityName
```

the jhipster-my-module does not start into post entity creation phase.

Answer (score 2):

Debbuging the *generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js* the error is *modules.push is not a function*

This happen with the **generator-jhipster** version 5.0.0, instead using the 4.14.4 it works.

If you don't need to develop your jhipster-module with version 5.0.0 of generator-jhipster you can use the 4.14.4 version, e.g.

```
...
"dependencies": {
   "generator-jhipster": "^4.14.4",
...
```

But it remains the open point on 5.0.0 version.